# I need to install multiple products (android application) on same device

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have an android application which consists of a sqlite database. The database is what that determines what product it is. To illustrate say i have different databases of tourism details for different states. Each database size is of 10+ MB and one single product would be an android application containing a database (as asset) for a particular state.

The challenge I'm facing is how to install multiple such products on a single device?
Thanks in advance for the suggestions and help

Comment: Is the user can change state after installing the app?

Comment: i assume change state here means switch to a different product. That is not an option in version 1 though.

Comment: Hi Shem i think i now need to consider the switch of products within the app earlier than planned. i may go for that in 1.1. Also pls see my comment in below answer regarding the same. thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your code in a library project and create a new project for each of your products.

Each project will include the library project and will have a unique package name and the required database file.

Library projects:
http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

Comment: I also have an idea of switching the database run time depending on the product icon chosen from the application dashboard.